# glBindTexture não aplica textura em GL_QUADS

Tags: c++, opengl

Problema: glBindTexture não aplica a textura em "GL_QUADS" ao usar OPENGL em C++.

Minha experiência em c++, e principalmente em OPENGL é limitada, porém, me baseei [neste código](https://gist.github.com/mortennobel/5299151). Fiz alguma poucas modificações para torná-lo compatível com meu projeto. As modificações podem ser observadas na reprodução abaixo.

Ao testar o código original, verifiquei que funciona. Mas esta modificação, fez com que a textura não fosse aplicada. Os "GL_QUADS" são criados, tudo funciona perfeitamente, exceto, a textura.

NOTA: Observei algumas questões relacionadas ao assunto, aqui no "stackoverflow", porém, as repostas não foram suficientes para mim. Ainda segui um [tutorial](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/opengl/CG_Introduction.html) da Nanyang Technological Uuniversity.

Fico agradecido por qualquer ajuda.

```c
bool loadPngImage(char *name, struct pnhImage *img){ //int &outWidth, int &outHeight, bool &outHasAlpha, GLubyte **outData); // TESTADO NO CODIGO ORIGINAL LINK https://gist.github.com/mortennobel/5299151
bool loadTexturePNG(char *filepath, struct pnhImage *img);
void buildQuadradoColorText(char webcolor[7], GLuint tID, float x, float y, float w, float h){;
void desenhar();

bool initGL(int argc, char** argv){  
  glutInit(&argc, argv);                              // Initialize GLUT  
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE);                   // Set double buffered mode
  glutCreateWindow("OpenGL Setup Test");              // Create a window with the given title
  glutInitWindowSize(Tela.width, Tela.height);        // Set the window's initial width & height          
  glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);                       // Position the window's initial top-left corner
  glutFullScreen();                                   // Exibe em tela cheia  
  glutDisplayFunc(desenhar);                          // Register display callback handler for window re-paint        
  glutReshapeFunc(winResize);                         // Register callback handler for window re-size event    
  glutMouseFunc(mouseEvent);                          // EVENTOS DO MOUSE
  glutMotionFunc(MotionCallback);                     // MONITORA MOVIMENTOS DO MOUSE COM BOTAO ATIVO 
  glutPassiveMotionFunc(passiveMotionCallback);       // MONITORA MOVIMENTO DE MOUSE COM BOTAO INATIVO
  glutSpecialFunc(keyPressEspecial);                  // EVENTOS DE TECLAS ESPECIAIS  
  glutTimerFunc( refreshFrame, Timer, 0);             // First timer call immediately

  glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);               // Black and opaque

  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  // The following two lines enable semi transparent
  glEnable(GL_BLEND);
  glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);  

  glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);   
  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

  return true;
}

bool loadTexturePNG(char *filepath, struct pnhImage *img){
  std::cout << "Carregando textura '" << filepath << "' ";     

  // CARREGA O TILE DO SOLO
  if (loadPngImage(filepath, img)){                
    img->tID = 0;

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    // CRIA UMA TEXTURA OPEGL
    glGenTextures(1, &img->tID );        

    std::cout << ">> tID: '" << img->tID << "' ";        

    // "Bind" a textura recém-criado: todas as funções textura futuras irá modificar esta textura
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, img->tID);        

    // FORNECE A IMAGEM AO OPNGL
    glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
                  0,
                  img->alpha ? 4 : 3, 
                  img->width,
                  img->height, 
                  0, 
                  img->alpha ? GL_RGBA : GL_RGB,
                  GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                  img->data
    ); 

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

    // Quando Ampliar a Imagem (sem mipmap maior disponível), use filtragem LINEAR
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    // Quando minifying a imagem, use uma mistura linear de dois mipmaps, cada filtrada linearmente também
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1); 

    // Gera mipmaps, pelo caminho.
    //glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);    

    // APAGAMOS/LIBERAMOS A IMAGE QUE JAH FOI CARREGADA PARA O OPENGL
    //SDL_FreeSurface(img->data);            

    if (glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR){
      std::cout << "[FALHA]" << std::endl;            
      return false;
    }          

    std::cout << "[OK] " << std::endl;

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);            

    return true;
  }else
    std::cout << "[FALHA] " << std::endl;

  return false;
}

// X -> LEFT POINT, Y, TOP POINT, W -> WIDTH, H -> HEIGHT
void buildQuadradoColorText(char webcolor[7], GLuint tID, float x, float y, float w, float h){
  struct rgbColor cor = WebColorTORgb(webcolor); // CONVERT HEX TO INT RGB

  glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);      

  glColor3f (cor.r, cor.g, cor.b); // ISSO FUNCIONA, E A OMISSAO NAO INTERFERE
  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tID); 

  // Draw a Red 1x1 Square centered at origin
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);            // Each set of 4 vertices form a quad   
    printf("texture id: %d.\n", tID );

    glTexCoord2f(0  , 0);
    glVertex2f( x   , y   );    // x, y

    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    glVertex2f( x+w , y   );

    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    glVertex2f( x+w , y-h );     

    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    glVertex2f( x   , y-h );                

  glEnd();

  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);  
}

void desenhar(){  
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);     // Clear the color buffer (background)          

  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);                             // To operate on Model-View matrix
  glLoadIdentity();  

  buildQuadradoColorText((char*)"#24a621", tID, -1, 1, 2, 2);         

  // MANDA O GRAFICO RENDERIZADO PARA A JANELA
  glutSwapBuffers();         
}
```

Comment: Seria melhor você detalhar o que mudou no código, assim fica difícil saber qual o problema. Dica: Esse código usa o OpenGL versão < 3.1, que ninguém mais recomenda utilizar, se você está só dando manutenção em uma aplicação já existente, tudo bem. Agora se está criando algo novo, recomendo veemente que faça utilizando OpenGL 3.2+, Você pode ter os primeiros passos a partir desse site: http://open.gl

Comment: @paulocanedo , obrigado por sua atenção, estou usando OPENGL 4.5. Relativo a mudança, o que ocorreu foi que o código original texturizava um quadrado diretamente, eu transformei isso em uma função loadTexturePNG, que carrega um PNG e indexa a um índice usando glBindTexture. Isso permite que um mesmo código (função) seja usado para carregar várias texturas distintas (arquivos), e também permite a reutilização da textura com glBindTexture + ID da textura. Foi o que entendo sobre o funcionamento glBindTexture. Portanto, carrego PNGs, vinculando a ID de texturas, e depois as reutilizo.

Comment: @paulocaned O objetivo de criar uma função que carregue e indexe as texturas, é evitar que toda vez que a janela for redesenhada, seja necessário recarregar o aquivo do HD, e ainda transformá-lo em textura. Isso ocuparia processamento desnecessário. Os índices de textura são salvos num vetor de struct, para esta finalidade.

Answer (score 0):

Descobri a solução, e o problema se encontrava na função **loadTexturePNG**. Embora eu admita que não entendo realmente o motivo, o teste de compilação verificou que a mudanças corrigiram o problema.

Caso alguém queira complementar explicando o motivo por que esta solução foi bem sucedida, fico agradecido.

1. Substituir **glTexParameteri** por **glTexParameterf**;
2. Comentar ou exclua a linha:

```c
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
```

Pronto, a texturização funciona! Veja a função alterada:

```c
/* CARREGA UMA IMAGEM PNG DE TEXTURA PARA O OPENGL */
bool loadTexturePNG(char *filepath, struct pnhImage *img, bool desbind = true){
  std::cout << "Carregando textura '" << filepath << "' ";     

  // CARREGA O TILE DO SOLO
  if (loadPngImage(filepath, img)){                
    img->tID = 0;   

    // CRIA UMA TEXTURA OPEGL
    glGenTextures(1, &img->tID );        

    std::cout << ">> tID: '" << img->tID << "' ";        

    // "Bind" a textura recém-criado: todas as funções textura futuras irá modificar esta textura
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, img->tID);        

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    // FORNECE A IMAGEM AO OPNGL
    glTexImage2D(
                  GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
                  0,
                  img->alpha ? 4 : 3, 
                  img->width,
                  img->height, 
                  0, 
                  img->alpha ? GL_RGBA : GL_RGB,
                  GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                  img->data
    ); 

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT);

    // Quando Ampliar a Imagem (sem mipmap maior disponível), use filtragem LINEAR    
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);                 

    // Quando minifying a imagem, use uma mistura linear de dois mipmaps, cada filtrada linearmente também
    //glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);

    // Gera mipmaps, pelo caminho.
    //glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);    

    // APAGAMOS/LIBERAMOS A IMAGE QUE JAH FOI CARREGADA PARA O OPENGL
    //SDL_FreeSurface(img->data);            

    if (glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR){
      std::cout << "[FALHA]" << std::endl;            
      return false;
    }          

    std::cout << "[OK] " << std::endl;

    if (desbind)
      glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    // LIBERA A IMAGEM DA MEMORIA
    free(img->data);

    return true;
  }else
    std::cout << "[FALHA] " << std::endl;

  return false;
}
```